# Sorting ints in java returns negative numbers first?

Tags: java, sorting

I have a comparator like so:

```
Collections.sort( sortedPlayers, new Comparator<RoundPlayer>()
{
    public int compare(RoundPlayer p1, RoundPlayer p2)
    {
        return p1.getScore() - p2.getScore();
    }
});
```

Sorted players is a list of player objects, the scores they return are ints such as, 200, -300, 1000 etc.

The goal of the comparator is to sort them so they are descending order, 1000, 200, -300.

However this comparator seems to return erratic results. Often with negative numbers coming out first.

Comment: Is it erratic or in ascending order?

Comment: It appears erratic, however the way its setup, I have only been able to test it with a small number of players putting in scores.

Comment: Negative numbers always come before positive numbers in natural ordering. http://www.mathatube.com/sitebuilder/images/number-line-600x271.png

Comment: I am almost wondering if somehow it is ordering it by magnitude instead of sequential order....  Could you provide an input example with the corresponding output?

Comment: What is the return type of `getScore()`? Could there be integer under/overflow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just reverse your return value you currently have

**sample**

```
return p2.getScore() - p1.getScore(); //will sort in descending order
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to sort by descending order then consider wrapping your `Comparator` using [Collections.reverseOrder(Comparator cmp)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder%28java.util.Comparator%29).

Also note that subtracting the two values is a bad idea because of integer overflow. Your `compare` logic is `p1.getScore() - p2.getScore()`. Consider
p1.score = 2147483647, p2.score = -2147483648, your comparator would return -1, incorrectly indicating p1's score is **less than** p2's score.

The correct logic is to test for <, = and >, returning -1, 0 and 1. Better yet, `Integer` already implements this logic so you can simply delegate to its `compareTo` method.

```
return Integer.valueOf(p1.getScore()).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(p2.getScore());
```

Comment: I searched "android sort negative numbers object list" on Google and she directed me here to your great explanation as the first result. 

It seems it would be a rare case of problem but I was trying to sort a list of MediaStore files based on their Bucket Ids that with an error I noticed negative values of bucket ids could be the source of problem.
Your info helped me a lot.